# How to select only one element when there's duplicate classes?

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to select only one class that have the same name, I don't know how to select only one of the same classes, as it keeps selecting all of the classes.

I'm just stuck at this point where I can't change the first class when there's the same named one. I have tried selecting them separately, but they just keep being connected.

```html
<main>
  <article>
    <section class="container description">
      <h3>Description</h3>
      <p>This peanut butter and jelly sandwich is my favorite sandwich. It has the perfect balance of ingredients and looks great when made right.</p>
    </section>

    <section class="container">
      <img src="https://image.flaticon.com/icons/png/512/63/63035.png" alt="sandwich" width="200" height="200">
      <h3>Ingredients</h3>
      <ul>
        <li>2 slices of white bread</li>
        <li>1 jar of grape jelly</li>
        <li>1 jar of creamy peanut butter</li>
        <li>A butter knife</li>
        <li>A sharp knife</li>
        <li>A cutting board</li>
      </ul>
    </section>

    <section class="container description">
      <h3>Directions</h3>
      <ol>
        <li>Lay both slices of bread next to each other on a cutting board.</li>
        <li>With the butter knife, spread a 1/8 inch layer of peanut butter on the left side</li>
        <li>On the right side, spread a 1/8 inch layer of jelly.</li>
        <li>Carefully place the two halves together so that the jelly is on top.</li>
        <li>With the sharp knife, carefully cut the sandwich in half.</li>
        <li>Enjoy the PB&amp;J!</li>
      </ol>
    </section>
  </article>
</main>
```

I expect the first section to have a text aligned to the center, but the second `.container.description` has to stay in its place without changing it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use css3 selectors like below.

```
/*This will select second section*/
    article .container:nth-child(2){
    background-color:#000;
    }
```

More detail see this [link](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css_selectors.asp)

Comment: Thank you!
Exactly what I needed, totally forgot about this one.